# Why I got an invalid bucket name error using dvc mlflow on macos

Tags: docker, mlflow, mlops, dvc

Could anyone tell what's the reason for error:

botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$"

I try to use mlflow with docker.
.env file contains:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_S3_BUCKET=vla...rts
MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:9000
MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://127.0.0.1:5000
POSTGRES_USER=...
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
POSTGRES_DB=test_db
```

Also tried to use:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_S3_BUCKET=vla...rts
MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://localhost:9000
MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=http://localhost:5000
POSTGRES_USER=...
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...
POSTGRES_DB=test_db
```

docker-compose contains:

```
... 
   mlflow:
        restart: always
        image: mlflow_server
        container_name: mlflow_server
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
        networks:
          - postgres
          - s3
        environment:
          - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
          - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
          - MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://nginx:9000
        command: mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db/${POSTGRES_DB} --default-artifact-root s3://${AWS_S3_BUCKET}/ --host 0.0.0.0
...
```

As I understood, I get an exception cause bucket name is empty (""). But in .env file I set bucket name as `vla...rts`

Comment: I've noticed, that problem problem arises in s3_artifact_repo.py. If we after (bucket, dest_path) = data.parse_s3_uri(self.artifact_uri) add bucket="arts", everything goes ok and dvc repro finishes successfully. But, unfortunately artifacts in mlflow experiments are empty

Comment: Have you set a remote name in DVC configuration? It should be in the .dvc/config file. See also https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote `add` and `modify`.

Comment: Omg, I guess, you're right. I'm trying to teach how to build MLOps pipeline. So, firstly, I used one s3 bucket. But when I tried to use docker, I decided to use minio s3 bucket. I'll try to modify dvc config and tell you about the results=)

Comment: p.s. I'm not sure `AWS_S3_BUCKET` is an env var that the AWS CLI (thus botocore, thus DVC) looks at :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the DVC remote URL in DVC config (.dvc/config file) ([ref](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/config)). In this case it should be something like `s3://vla...rts`.

This is usually set with `dvc remote add`, but it can be reset manually or with `dvc remote modify` ([ref](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#available-parameters-per-storage-type)).

Answer (score 0):

OMG, It was very strange issue. It wasn't a problem with dvc. Everything was  configured perfect.
So I get this exception
[image]

And I've changed only 1 thing - the name of experiment in train stage:
mlflow.set_experiment("xgboost") -> mlflow.set_experiment("xgboost_2")
And that's all!